# iPad2 camera display not showing

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, ipad-2

I have an iPhone app that displays the camera using UIImagePicker to take a picture. I am porting it to iPad2 and when i want to display the camera (through a modalviewcontroller) i get the camera buttons but the display in the preview is just white. If i take the picture i can see it.

Does this happen to you?

Comment: Update: if i call [imagePicker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet]; on the imagepicker, i do see the camera display and the formSheet over it!

So i guess that when it is full screen the same is happening. What could be the reason for the modalviewcntroller's view to show OVER the imagepicker?

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem.  I moved the UIImagePicker code to my rootviewcontroller, and it worked.  I could see what was actually through the viewfinder.  It also worked via a popover in the existing viewcontroller (called next after the rootviewcontroller), but the resolution was poor when I displayed the photo.  This is not satisfactory, but I guess I found a workaround if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday only i have tried this code to use camera to take pics. from my app and it worked on iphone after porting it.

I think you need to call takePicture method on the controller.

Just a guess.

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    if(sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        [picker takePicture];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't change anything... I still see a blank screen instead of the camera.